# Usar caracteres <>, =, &&, || en strings.xml

Tags: android-studio

he intentado poner un código de ejemplo en un String, el problema es que el código presenta dichos caracteres como este ejemplo:

```
 <string name="funcion3">
    public static calificaciones(){
    int calif =0;
  int aprob=0, reprob=0;
  int e=0, mb=0, b=0, s=0;
  for(int i=0; i20; i++){
     calif = (int) (Math.random()*101);
     System.out.print(calif + " ");
     if(calif>=0 &amp;&amp; calif<=69 ) reprob++;
     if(calif>=70 &amp;&amp; calif  <=100) aprob++;
     if(calif>=96  &amp;&amp; calif<=100) e++;
     if(calif>=90  &amp;&amp; calif<=95) mb++;
     if(calif>=80  &amp;&amp;  calif<=89) b++;
     if(calif>=70  &amp;&amp; calif<=79) s++;
  }//for
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Reprobados: " + reprob);
  System.out.println("Aprobados: " + aprob);
  System.out.println("Excelentes: " + e);
  System.out.println("Muy buenos: " + mb);
  System.out.println("Buenos: " + b);
  System.out.println("Suficientes: " + s);
    }//
</string>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 y en mi archivo de string me marca algo así:

> tag name spected

quisiera saber que puedo hacer para resolver esto ya que me es muy importante poner el código como ejemplo con dichos caracteres para una mejor comprensión.

Comment: En que línea muestra ese mensaje? Agrega el código del ejemplo que deseas realizar, saludos.

Comment: me los muestra al ponerlos en un string 
editare la pregunta para que lo vea

Comment: Por lo que veo quieres almacenar algo así como un fragmento de código dentro de un recurso string. Para lograr mostrar caracteres especiales tendrás que escaparlos ([leer aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling)).  Pero me temo que te enfrentas a algo complicado, porque 1º no estoy seguro de que Android te permita escapar todos los caracteres y 2º supongo que vas a querer presentar el fragmento de código identado. Para ello, en caso de que logres crear la cadena, tendrás que formatearlo a mano, no creo que exista un recurso específico.

Comment: esto me ha funcionado muy bien gracias

Comment: creo que tu codigo va a agregar datos especiales a tu XML , si es asi puedes usar [CDATA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) puedes leer un poco mas en [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)

Comment: @bryanibarraalonso hola, cuando obtienes texto desde strings.xml, en el caso de los caracteres que tienes problemas, debes realizar una conversión a su equivalente en html. Me imagino deseas realizar un tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar caracteres dentro de `strings.xml` es importante que estos sean codificados, tal como lo realizas con el caracter `&`  , que es codificado como `&amp;`, puedes realizarlo de acuerdo a [esta tabla](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html).
Ejemplos:

`<`  sería `&lt;`

`>` sería `&gt;`

`&` sería `&amp;`

`"` sería `&quot;`

En internet puedes encontrar varios recursos para codificar los caracteres a su versión HTML, por ejemplo este [codificador/decodificador](https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder):

Es importante hacer uso del método [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html), el cual realizará la representación del html.

```
String htmlText = getResources().getString(R.string.funcion3);
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Este sería el texto codificado el cual puedes obtener de `strings.xml` para tu aplicación y funcionará correctamente:

```
<resources>

    <string name="funcion3">
        public static calificaciones(){
        int calif =0; int aprob=0, reprob=0; int e=0, mb=0, b=0, s=0; for(int i=0; i20; i++){
        calif = (int) (Math.random()*101);
        System.out.print(calif + &quot; &quot;);
        if(calif&gt;=0 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif&lt;=69 )
        reprob++;
        if(calif&gt;=70 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif &lt;=100)
        aprob++;
        if(calif&gt;=96 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif&lt;=100)
        e++;
        if(calif&gt;=90 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif&lt;=95)
        mb++;
        if(calif&gt;=80 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif&lt;=89)
        b++;
        if(calif&gt;=70 &amp;amp;&amp;amp; calif&lt;=79) s++; }
        //for System.out.println();
        System.out.println(&quot;Reprobados: &quot; + reprob);
        System.out.println(&quot;Aprobados: &quot; + aprob);
        System.out.println(&quot;Excelentes: &quot; + e);
        System.out.println(&quot;Muy buenos: &quot; + mb);
        System.out.println(&quot;Buenos: &quot; + b);
        System.out.println(&quot;Suficientes: &quot; + s); }//
</string>

</resources>
```

---

Como comenta [@JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow), también se puede usar el contenedor [CDATA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) como es usado en JSON, pero en este caso no debes codificar ningún carácter a su versión html.

```
<resources>

    <string name="funcion3">
     <![CDATA[     
    public static calificaciones(){
    int calif =0;
    int aprob=0, reprob=0;
    int e=0, mb=0, b=0, s=0;
    for(int i=0; i20; i++){
       calif = (int) (Math.random()*101);
       System.out.print(calif + " ");
       if(calif>=0 && calif<=69 ) reprob++;
       if(calif>=70 && calif  <=100) aprob++;
       if(calif>=96 && calif<=100) e++;
       if(calif>=90  && calif<=95) mb++;
       if(calif>=80  &&  calif<=89) b++;
       if(calif>=70  && calif<=79) s++;
    }//for
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Reprobados: " + reprob);
    System.out.println("Aprobados: " + aprob);
    System.out.println("Excelentes: " + e);
    System.out.println("Muy buenos: " + mb);
    System.out.println("Buenos: " + b);
    System.out.println("Suficientes: " + s);
      }//
    ]]>
</string>
</resources>
```

y puedes obtener el texto si realizar ninguna conversión:

```
String htmlText = getResources().getString(R.string.funcion3);
myTextView.setText(htmlText);
```

Comment: mira lo que encontre, se puede usar [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490125/5695795) que es un standard de XML , no puedo comprobarlo porque no trabajo con android :(, de hecho lo agregue al comentario en la pregunta

Comment: @JackNavaRow si se puede solo que no debe tener ningún texto codificado, creo que es mucho mejor opción la que comentas en este caso que quiere cargar código en su aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo el string probado en Android Studio.

```
<string name="funcion3">
public static calificaciones(){ \n
int calif =0; \n
int aprob=0, reprob=0;\n
int e=0, mb=0, b=0, s=0;\n
for(int i=0; i20; i++){\n
 calif = (int) (Math.random()*101);\n
 System.out.print(calif + " ");\n
 if(calif>=0 &amp;&amp; calif&lt;=69 ) reprob++;\n
 if(calif>=70 &amp;&amp; calif  &lt;=100) aprob++;\n
 if(calif>=96  &amp;&amp; calif&lt;=100) e++;\n
 if(calif>=90  &amp;&amp; calif&lt;=95) mb++;\n
 if(calif>=80  &amp;&amp;  calif&lt;=89) b++;\n
 if(calif>=70  &amp;&amp; calif&lt;=79) s++;\n
}//for\n
System.out.println();\n
System.out.println("Reprobados: " + reprob);\n
System.out.println("Aprobados: " + aprob);\n
System.out.println("Excelentes: " + e);\n
System.out.println("Muy buenos: " + mb);\n
System.out.println("Buenos: " + b);\n
System.out.println("Suficientes: " + s);\n
}//
</string>
```

Explicación:
Esto se carga en el archivo de string.xml dentro de la carpeta res/values cuando quieras cargar dicho string coges el textview que quieras mostras i le pones R.string.funcion3 y te cargara todo ese string, hay que poner los simbolos de <>, =, &&, || en codigo ASCII y el simbolo de \n son los saltos de carros si quieres agregar espacios tendras que poner &nspb;

Asi en cualquier tipo de string. También se puede hacer por programación pero mejor es cargar los textos en dicho archivos por el tema de los idiomas de la app.

Comment: podrias agregar por lo menos una explicacion

Comment: Explicacion agregada JackNavaRow